# EXT-JS date format for datefield on form submit

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using EXT JS to build a form that allows for user input. One of the fields is a datefield, when the form is submitted I would like the value being sent over HTTP to be the "long" value (or milliseconds) representation of the date, instead of the normal: 'dd/mm/yyyy' format.

I've searched A LOT and cannot find any answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure the format of the datefield's submitted date value using its [`submitFormat`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-submitFormat) config.  Try:

`submitFormat: 'U000'`

Answer (score 3):

In ExtJs 3.x there is no `submitFormat` config property for default `datefield`, but in 4.x it is.

There are several custom created plugins/extensions, which can help.
E.g.:
[XDateField](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?25900-XDateField-with-configurable-submitFormat) and [DatePickerPlus](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?31553-Ext.ux.DatePickerPlus-MultiMonth-MultiSelection-WeekNumbers-Custom-CSS-Days-...&p=148587)